# string index out of range? - python

Tags: python, string, int

im buliding a chat and i'm keep getting the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ronen/Documents/CyberLink/tryccc.py", line 651, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/ronen/Documents/CyberLink/tryccc.py", line 630, in main
    print_message(data_from_server, len(temp_message), username)
  File "C:/Users/ronen/Documents/CyberLink/tryccc.py", line 265, in print_message
    temp_l = data[0]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

i am trying to get the first char of the data string and convert it into int but i get this error
the problem is in the first line of the code

```
def print_message(d_temp, line_length, this_username):
    temp_l = d_temp[0]  #the problematic line
    len_username = int(temp_l)
    username_sender = d_temp[1:(len_username + 1)]
    message_sent = d_temp[(len_username + 1): -4]
    hour_time = d_temp[-4: -2]
    min_time = d_temp[-2:]
    printed_message = "\r" + hour_time + ":" + min_time + " " + username_sender + " : " + message_sent
    print printed_message,  # Prints this message on top of what perhaps this client started writing.
    # if this client started typing message
    complete_line_with_space(len(printed_message), line_length)
```

data- the data (string) from the server

line_length - the length of the temp massage

this_username - the client's username

thank you to all the helpers

Comment: Might be `d_temp` is empty..

Comment: What should the function do if `d_temp` has a length of zero? If you're thinking, "that should never happen", are you 100% sure it can never happen?

Comment: your error doesn't match the code

Answer (score 0):

empty `d_temp` will give this error.
This might be the reason:

```
>>> d_temp = ""
>>> d_temp[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `print_message` is executed with an empty string as first parameter

```
print_message("",...)
```

This means the problem is somewhere else in your code.